# how to connect zookeeper after deploying helm chart in gke?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, vmware, ytt

we are creating a vmware carvel package, I need do a sanity check for zookeeper, how can i check the output in gke?

Zookeeper output

[image]

Curl and localhost is failing to connect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your service type is `ClusterIP` which is not available from outside the Kubernetes cluster. There are two ways you could do this

If you need to really access this regularly from outside the cluster, you should deploy a service of type `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` or an ingress. These would be reachable from outside

If you only want to check something quickly, you can temporarily make zookeeper visible with

```
kubectl port-forward zookeeper-0 2181
```